# OpenCV Face Recognition strange result

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I have been using OpenCV's SVM and RF for a multi-class face recognition problem with 11 classes and only 5 images per class. I used two kinds of features - initially a toy intensity image feature (just each image resized to 32x32 grayscale) and then the second feature was simply another toy feature using Tan Triggs preprocessing([link](https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/blob/master/misc/tan_triggs.cpp)). Here is the feature code:

```
void Feature::makeFeature(cv::Mat &image, cv::Mat &result)
{
    cv::resize( image, image, cv::Size(32, 32), 0, 0, cv::INTER_CUBIC );
    cv::equalizeHist(image, image);
// Images must be aligned - Only pitch executed, yaw and roll assumed   negligible
    algmt->getAlignedImage( image, image ); // image alignment
// tan triggs
{
tan_triggs_preprocessing(image, result);
result = result.reshape(0, 1); // make a single row vector, needed for the training samples matrix
}
// if plain intensity
{
//    image.copyTo(result);
//    result.convertTo(result, CV_32F, 1.0f/255.0f);
//    result = result.reshape(0, 1); // make a single row vector, needed for the training samples matrix
}
}
```

Where the tan_triggs_preprocessing function is the same as the Tan Triggs preprocessing function given in the link. I added one step - i normalized the result between 0 and 1.

The results on test for both were not very good, as expected, but then I made a silly mistake and discovered something strange: When I accidentally gave the training directory as input for both training and test, I get 100% results on the plain intensity feature, but the Tan Triggs feature gives the following as result:

**SVM Training Complete**
**Total number of correct: 51 and accuracy: 92.7273**
**RF Training Complete**
**Total number of correct: 53 and accuracy: 96.3636**

I do know however much you overfit the result should be perfect when the training set is input to test. Everything else is standard, both SVM and RF are standard as in the OpenCV examples. Besides I get 100% for plain intensity feature so of course I am mucking something up here when using Tan Triggs. Anyone has any idea what mistake I am making?
I have used other complex features like LTPs and LQPs without issue, but this preprocessing method is something I want to use. I use the Jain-Learned Miller congealing algorithm for alignment as I assume frontals for face recognition, no pose correction.

Comment: "When I accidentally gave the training directory as input for both training and test, I get 100% results" - that's to be expected. you only get a 'real' prediction, if you exclude the test images from the train set. (and results will be obviously *worse*)

Comment: still, i'd be curious, what you params you choose for SVM / RF. would you mind adding them to your question ?

Comment: Exactly my point - if you give training dir as input to both training and test, you "should" get 100% but I don't get it when using the Tan Triggs preprocessed intensity features, which is what is weird and I want to know why I am not getting 100%. 
I used svm.train_auto for SVM and for the RF, I used min depth 20, number of trees 400 (this is where I get highest cross validation scores) and categories 16. For SVM, train_auto gives a C of 2.25 and gamma of 1.25.

Comment: tan-triggs never worked for me nicely (normalized, too). (and thanks for your helpful numbers)